# Use different IP-s for different Laravel Homestead apps

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

When using Homestead for local development, by default the IP in **Homestead.yaml** is set to `192.168.10.10`. Example Homestead.yaml with multiple applications looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/MyUser/workspace/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: app1.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/app1/public
    - map: app2.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/app2/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Then, this IP is used in **hosts** file:

```
192.168.10.10 app1.local
192.168.10.10 app2.local
```

Let's say I would like to use separate IP for each application. Is it possible? How do I do it?

Comment: .htaccess could help here.

Comment: Hi, care to elaborate on this .htaccess idea? Remember we're talking about environment based on Homestead.

Comment: Out of sheer curiousity, why would you want to use multiple IP addresses? You could just use multiple aliases in your hosts file to run multiple instances of homestead.

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck Hi, it's not easy to explain, unfortunately, you would need to see it yourself :) The thing is, I'm running two apps, both of them communicate with a single sign-on auth server. During the development I've been getting weird behaviour of Session and Request objects. This weird behaviour stops occurring as soon as I deploy both apps to their servers. So, my idea is the same will work locally and that is way I'm looking for a way to separate the apps on Homestead.

Comment: Well, each homestead instance is already separated so it sounds like it might be an issue with the middle man: the sign-on auth server.

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck Could be. But what do you mean exactly by "Homestead instance"? I have only one Homestead virtual machine running, this machine serves my apps, along with phpMyAdmin, all on `192.168.10.10` host.

Comment: Well, I was referring to each site as, at least from what I read when installing homestead on my machine, it seemed that they were kept isolated from each other file wise.  Keep in mind I am still relatively new with laravel so if I might say(metaphorically) something inaccurate, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xx\.xx\.[8-9]$ # your ip here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/
RewriteRule .? /index/ [R,L]
```

The above will redirect based on a certain IP-address.

See this: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_redirect_all_visitors_except_your_ip_to_another_site/

*You can modify things to your needs of course. This are just samples.